# Convergence of "samples" of a function in Lp

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Given $u\in W^{1,p}([0,L])$, for each $n \in \Bbb N$ , split the interval $[0,L]$ into $n+1$ sub intervals of the form $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ where $x_i = \dfrac{iL}{n}$

and define for each $n $

$u_n:[x_i,x_{i+1}] \to \Bbb R$ by $u_n(x) = u(x_i)+\dfrac{n(u(x_{i+1}-u(x_i))}{L}(x-x_i)$

That is, $u_n$ is the "lines" connecting $u(x_i)$ to $u(x_{i+1})$.

I'm trying to show that $u_n\to u$ in $L^p(0,L)$ but with no success , I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary proof for $p\in (1,\infty)$. More advanced arguments
can be found in textbooks on finite element methods.

Let $e:= u_n-u$. Then $e(x_i)=0$ for all $i$.
By the fundamental theorem, we get (with $p>1$)
$$
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |e(x)|^p dx =
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \int_{x_i}^x p e'(s)sign(e(s))|e(s)|^{p-1} ds \ dx.
$$
The inner integral of right-hand side can be estimated by
$$
\int_{x_i}^x  e'(s)sign(e(s))e(s)^{p-1} ds 
\le \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |e'(s)|\cdot |e(s)|^{p-1}ds
$$
Summing these integrals gives with $h:=L/n=x_{i+1}-x_i$
$$
\|e\|_p^p \le h\int_0^L |e'(s)|\cdot |e(s)|^{p-1}ds
\le\left( \int_0^L |e'(s)|^pds \right)^{1/p} 
\left( \int_0^L |e(s)|^pds \right)^{(p-1)/p} 
= h \|e'\|_{p} \|e\|_p^{p-1},
$$
which proves $\|e\|_p\le h \|e'\|_{p}$.

It remains to show that $\|e'\|_{p}$ is bounded wrt $n$. We have $e'(x) = h^{-1} ( u(x_{i+1}-u(x_i))  - u'(x)$
for $x\in (x_i,x_{i+1})$. We know $u'\in L^p$, so it remains to investigate the difference quotient contribution:
$$
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |h^{-1} ( u(x_{i+1})-u(x_i))|^p
= h^{1-p} |u(x_{i+1})-u(x_i)|^p
$$
and
$$
|u(x_{i+1})-u(x_i)| \le \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |u'(s)|ds
\le \left(\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |u'(s)|^pds\right)^{1/p}\cdot h^{(p-1)/p},
$$
so
$$
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |h^{-1} ( u(x_{i+1})-u(x_i))|^p
\le h^{1-p} \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |u'(s)|^pds\cdot h^{(p-1)}
$$
and $\|e'\|_p \le 2 \|u'\|_p$.